# Fatal Error in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am getting fatal error at `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery` can anyone tell what is wrong with this code??

```
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO placement (S.NO,STUDENT NAME,BATCH,COMPANY NAME) values (@S.NO,@STUDENT NAME,@BATCH,@COMPANY NAME)"))
        {

        using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@S.NO", sno);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STUDENT NAME", name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BATCH",batch);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COMPANY NAME",companyname);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the error in specific?

Answer (score 0):

1. In the INSERT INTO placement statement, the brackets must contain the attribute names.
2. Leave the blanks out of your parameter names.

The following works for a table with columns Location, Name, Room, Phone:

```
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(dbConnectString);

        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO table1 (Location, Name,  Room, Phone) values (@LOCATION.L1,@STUDENT,@ROOM,@PHONE.NR)"))
        {

            using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LOCATION.L1", "Paris");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STUDENT", "Harris");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ROOM", "Room 123");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PHONE.NR", "4711");
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

And, in case you get an exception, you may have a look into innerException to get more detailed information.

In case you have blank characters in your column names, the suggestion is to remove them (considered bad practice). Otherwise, you have to enclose these names in your sql queries with the special character `, which is NOT the same as the character '.